# Formula for the first Monday (or Weekday) of the Month

Tags: formula, formula-field

How can I find the first Monday (or a given Weekday) of the Month? For example, this month Jan 2015, the first Monday is Jan 5th 2015?

Answer (score 1):

Add a certain number of days from the first day of the month based on the weekday value of the first day of the month.

```
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()),
  CASE(MOD(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7),
    0, 2,
    1, 1,
    2, 7,
    3, 6,
    4, 5,
    5, 4,
    6, 3,
  0)
)
```

Comment: Could you please accept this answer, so it is clear the issue is resolved?